# Parsing JSON with python: blank fields

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-2.7

I'm having problems while parsing a JSON with python, and now I'm stuck.
The problem is that the entities of my JSON are not always the same. The JSON is something like:

```
"entries":[
{
"summary": "here is the sunnary",
"extensions": {
   "coordinates":"coords",
   "address":"address",
   "name":"name"
   "telephone":"123123"
   "url":"www.blablablah"
},
}
]
```

I can move through the JSON, for example:

```
for entrie in entries:
  name =entrie['extensions']['name']
  tel=entrie['extensions']['telephone']
```

The problem comes because sometimes, the JSON does not have all the "fields", for example, the `telephone` field, sometimes is missing, so, the script fails with `KeyError`, because the key *telephone* is missing in this entry.
So, my question: how could I run this script, leaving a blank space where *telephone* is missing?
I've tried with:

```
if entrie['extensions']['telephone']:
    tel=entrie['extensions']['telephone']
```

but I think is not ok.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `dict.get` instead of `[]`:

```
entries['extensions'].get('telephone', '')
```

Or, simply:

```
entries['extensions'].get('telephone')
```

`get` will return the second argument (default, `None`) instead of raising a `KeyError` when the key is not found.

Answer (score 8):

If the data is missing in only one place, then [*dict.get*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) can be used to fill-in missing the missing value:

```
tel = d['entries'][0]['extensions'].get('telelphone', '')
```

If the problem is more widespread, you can have the JSON parser use a [*defaultdict*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or custom dictionary instead of a regular dictionary.  For example, given the JSON string:

```
json_txt = '''{
    "entries": [
        {
            "extensions": {
                "telephone": "123123", 
                "url": "www.blablablah", 
                "name": "name", 
                "coordinates": "coords", 
                "address": "address"
            }, 
            "summary": "here is the summary"
        }
    ]
}'''
```

Parse it with:

```
>>> class BlankDict(dict):
        def __missing__(self, key):
            return ''

>>> d = json.loads(json_txt, object_hook=BlankDict)

>>> d['entries'][0]['summary']
u'here is the summary'

>>> d['entries'][0]['extensions']['color']
''
```

As a side note, if you want to clean-up your datasets and enforce consistency, there is a fine tool called [Kwalify](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/kwalify/) that does schema validation on JSON (and on YAML);

Comment: Nice, I like this better then `defaultdict` because inside the `__missing__` method one would be able to add some logic to catch a potential bug.  With `defaultdict` I always cringe because I won't get a KeyError when I make a typo.

Comment: `entries['extensions'].get('telephone', {}).get('anothermissingkey',{})`  is almost 3x as fast (on Deb9's py3.5) as `object_hook=BlankDict` approach, and it works for multiple levels

Answer (score 0):

There are several useful dictionary features that you can use to work with this.

First off, you can use `in` to test whether or not a key exists in a dictionary:

```
if 'telephone' in entrie['extensions']:
    tel=entrie['extensions']['telephone']
```

`get` might also be useful; it allows you to specify a default value if the key is missing:

```
tel=entrie['extensions'].get('telephone', '')
```

Beyond that, you could look into the standard library's `collections.defaultdict`, but that might be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways.

One is to make sure that your dictionaries are standard, and when you read them in they have all fields.  The other is to be careful when accessing the dictionaries.

Here is an example of making sure your dictionaries are standard:

```
__reference_extensions = {
   # fill in with all standard keys
   # use some default value to go with each key
   "coordinates" : '',
   "address" : '',
   "name" : '',
   "telephone" : '',
   "url" : ''
}

entrie = json.loads(input_string)
d = entrie["extensions"]
for key, value in __reference_extensions:
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = value
```

Here is an example of being careful when accessing the dictionaries:

```
for entrie in entries:
   name = entrie['extensions'].get('name', '')
   tel = entrie['extensions'].get('telephone', '')
```